# Where to get Gitlab's OpenID ID Token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab, openid-connect

Using Gitlab provided access tokens for the OpenID scope, i.e.

```
https://gitlab.com/oauth/userinfo?access_token=<bearer token>
```

returns a limited amount of information e.g. username, groups, etc. However, it does not return the user's email address.
The [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/openid_connect_provider.html) indicates that:

> The claims sub, sub_legacy, email and email_verified are included in
> the ID token, all other claims are available from the /oauth/userinfo
> endpoint used by OIDC clients.

**Given the AccessToken - *how do I retrieve the ID token*?**

**This is a known / discussed issue cf.* [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21662)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what **scopes** you ask for when you first send the initial authentication request to GitLab.

You need to ask for the **email** scope to get that information back and you should get the **ID-token** back at the same time as you get your first **access-token**.

Comment: I was suspecting that I'd have to include email in the scope. I was just uncertain from the way the OpenID scope was described. The ID token with the access token is pretty bare bones so I was hoping / thinking that wasn't it.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you obtain code through authorization request, you need to specify the scope, and the scope needs to include `openid`,`read_user`,`profile`,`email`.
2. When exchanging the token with the code obtained in the first step, you can return to `access_token` and `id_token`.
3. When the `access_token` obtained in the second step is used to obtain the user information, it can return the user's `e-mail`.

Refer to the explanation of the scope used above:

- `openid`: Grants permission to authenticate with GitLab using OpenID Connect. Also gives read-only access to the user's profile and group memberships.
- `read_user`: Grants read-only access to the authenticated user's profile through the /user API endpoint, which includes username, public email, and full name. Also grants access to read-only API endpoints under /users.
- `profile`: Grants read-only access to the user's profile data using OpenID Connect.
- `email`: Grants read-only access to the user's primary email address using OpenID Connect.